# Multiple linear regression in one plot (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, linear-regression

I am trying to plot 4 linear regressions in one plot!
I am comparing the tertiary enrollments over the years by separating

- 1. High-income level countries
- 2. Upper middle-income countries
- 3. Lower-middle income countries
- 4. Low-income countries.

what I have so far is

```
t <- ggplot(painel_df, aes(Year, E.tertiary, colour=income_group, fill=income_group)) +
  geom_smooth(method="lm") +
  geom_point(size=0.2) +
  theme_bw() + 
  xlab("Years") +
  ylab("School enrollments, tertiary (%gross)") 

plot(t)
```

The problem is that it's not giving me a trend line only the dots.
What I want to have is only the lines, because I think that with all the dots the plot gets very full of information

What I have is this

[image]

And what I want is something like this

[image]

Comment: Try changing `Years` to numeric, or adding `group = income_group` inside `aes`

Comment: as.numeric worked ! Thank you !